# How to dynamically define name of R.drawable

Tags: android, image, resources, drawable

Is there a way to generate R.drawable.... name on the fly? I want to set a background image with a dynamically generated name ( which is already usable as `R.drawable.example_graphic`)

So i want to find a way to assign a String to $ABC -> `btn.setBackgroundImage(R.drawable.$ABC);`

I don't want to create a new drawable, i want to use the existing one.

Comment: For those who are having the same problem: I am one of the upvoters of the above comment. However, i found with @CommonsWare's help that those solutions may require a cache which can be done using the solution of G.BlakeMeike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution, as @CommonsWare has shared.

`getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("flags_"+country, "drawable","mypackage")`

However, it may require cacheing as it uses reflection.

So, creating a static HashMap to keep the ResourceName and it's result from getIdentifier function (integer) seems to be a good idea; further usages for the same ResourceName will just get the value from HashMap instead of using the reflection again.

Comment: Note that this uses reflection, which is not especially fast. You may wish to cache the result.

Comment: so it is a good idea to mix this solution with @G.BlakeMeike's solution. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Drawables are constants at compile time: you know exactly what exists.  So, in your Application object, create a map:

```
public static final Map<String, Integer> NAMED_RESOURCES;
static {
  Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  m.put(KEY1, R.drawable.ABC);
  m.put(KEY2, R.drawable.DEF);
  // ...
  NAMED_RESOURCES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
```

now you can:

btn.setBackgroundImage(Application.NAMED_RESOURCES.get($ABC));

Comment: thank you for sharing this idea, however i have many resources (for example country flags), so it may not be good to use this solution for my case.

Comment: NP. Getting pipped by Mark is just part of participating in StackOverflow ;-)